# How to hand over arguments containing "-" in Bash?

Tags: bash, grep, terminal

I tried to use the `grep` command to search for a string like `-R` in a file. But the command thinks, that I am trying to hand over an option like `-i` for ignore case.

Comment: i think that you wrote the answer in your question ... use `"-R"` , not `-R`

Comment: @jsotola are you serious? to the op: use `grep -e -R ./-file1 file2`, where `-R` is a pattern starting with `-`, and `./-file1` is a filename starting with `-`.

Comment: The answer is here: [What does “--” (double-dash) mean? (also known as “bare double dash”)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/332764)

Comment: Thank you, @Freddy and pizdelect, both of your answers work for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to [escape](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32018/grep-and-escaping-a-dollar-sign) the characters `grep \\-R myfile.txt`:

Example:

```
$ touch test.txt
$ echo "-R" >> ./test.txt
$ cat test.txt
-R
$ grep \\-R ./test.txt
-R
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer also works for me!

Answer (score 3):

The `-e` option for `grep` is for explicitly saying "the next argument is the pattern":

```
grep -e -R file
```

The above would search for line matching `-R` in the file called `file`.

The `-e` option may occur multiple times on the command line, and `grep` will use all the given patterns (you will get the lines back that matches *any* of the patterns).

Answer (score 2):

As well as the previously mentioned answers, `--` is used to signify the end of options, allowing you to use patterns afterward that may resemble an argument without being interpreted undesirably:

```
$ echo -R | grep -- '-R'
-R
```