# How do I use grep to search for the string "-1"

Tags: grep, gnu

I'm using grep in bash to search for the string "-1" .

I would usually search for "bar" like this ...

```
glaucon@foo $ grep -irn "bar"
```

... which works fine but when I try to search for "-1" I get this ...

```
glaucon@foo $ grep -irn "-1"
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

... I thought the minus might be a special character but it appears not . I also tried using the 'fixed strings' option in case this was some aspect of regex I was unfamiliar with ...

```
glaucon@foo $ grep -irnF "-1"
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

... but, as shown, that doesn't provide output either.

I'm sure this is straightforward but ... how ?

Thanks

Comment: Related: [How to hand over arguments containing “-” in Bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523893/how-to-hand-over-arguments-containing-in-bash)

Comment: It seems that just escaping the "-" will work: `grep -irn "\-1"`

Comment: @guillermochamorro - thanks. I thought I had tried that but it turns out that I hadn't, that works. As you were first do you want to make this an answer I can mark as 'correct' ?

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for the link as a result of which I now know that this will also work : grep -irn -e "-1" .

Comment: @glaucon yes that's what I'd probably use in the special case of `grep`; for GNU utilities more generally, the `--` end-of-options placeholder is my go-to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option you have is to escape the dash `-` with a backslash `\`:

```
grep -irn "\-1"
```

Adding two dashes to mark the end of options (as suggested by @steeldriver):

```
grep -irn -- "-1"
```

Or, use `-e` to explicitly say "the next argument is the pattern":

```
grep -irn -e "-1"
```