# How to use the -E option of grep matching some variable name

Tags: shell, grep

We want to know about the correct method for matching some variable name(including its $ prefix) via using the grep -E option.
It seems that this grep macthing function can only work with either no any option or -e option ......

```
> 
> 
> grep ""'$'status"" /home/ewpadm/.sapenv_wzwms1.csh
if ( $status == 0 ) then
if ( $status == 0 ) then 
    set rc1 = $status
    set rc2 = $status
    set rc3 = $status
    set rc4 = $status
    set rc5 = $status
    set rc6 = $status
    set rc7 = $status
    set rc8 = $status
> 
> 
> grep -E ""'$'status"" /home/ewpadm/.sapenv_wzwms1.csh
> 
> 
> grep -E """'$'status"""" /home/ewpadm/.sapenv_wzwms1.csh
> 
> 
> grep -e ""'$'status"" /home/ewpadm/.sapenv_wzwms1.csh 
if ( $status == 0 ) then
if ( $status == 0 ) then 
    set rc1 = $status
    set rc2 = $status
    set rc3 = $status
    set rc4 = $status
    set rc5 = $status
    set rc6 = $status
    set rc7 = $status
    set rc8 = $status
> 
> 
> grep -e "= "'$'status"" /home/ewpadm/.sapenv_wzwms1.csh
    set rc1 = $status
    set rc2 = $status
    set rc3 = $status
    set rc4 = $status
    set rc5 = $status
    set rc6 = $status
    set rc7 = $status
    set rc8 = $status
> 
>
```

Comment: Related: [grep and escaping a dollar sign](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32021/65304)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` is a special character for both the shell (where it's used to introduce some expansions such as `$param`, `$(cmdsubst)`, `$((arithmetic))`) and for regular expressions (in all of *basic*, *extended* (`-E`, formerly `egrep`), *perl* (`-P` / `-X perl` / `--perl-regexp`...), *augmented* (`-X`/ `--augmented-regexp`)) where it means to match at the end of the subject, so you need to escape it for both, preferably with `'...'` for shells and with `\$` or `[$]` in regular expressions (`\` and `[...]` are also special in most shells and can also be quoted with `'...'`):

In basic RE (without `-E`/`-P`/`-X`...), `$` is only special at the end of the regexp or in some cases before a `\)` so here the regexp can be `$status`, while in other regexp variants including extended ones, it's generally always special so the regexp must be `\$status` or `[$]status`.

Using the `-F` option of `grep` (formerly `fgrep`) for *fixed strings* avoid having to do the regexp escaping. perl-like regexps also have `\Q...\E` for quoting. So, many options:

```
grep -F '$status'
grep    '$status'
grep    '\$status'
grep    '[$]status'
grep -E '\$status'
grep -E '[$]status'
```

Non-standard:

```
grep -P '\$status'
grep -P '[$]status'
grep -P '\Q$status\E'
grep -X '\$status'
grep -X '[$]status'
```

In some shells, `\` and `"` can also be used as quoting operators, but backslash and `$` are often still special within `"..."`, so that would make it awkward here. `'...'` are the strongest quotes (and in some shells such as `rc`  and derivatives, the only quotes), so are the ones you generally want to use around regexp where many of the operators (`^$*?\[](){}|`) also happen to be special in the syntax of most shells.

In any case, those will also find `$status` inside

- `$status2`, `$status_old` or `$statusing`
- `$$status` (`$$` followed by `status`)
- `\$status` or any csh quoting where `$status` is taken literally

And will not find

- `${status}`
- `${status[1]}` (subscripting)
- `${status:q}` (modifiers)
- `$#status` or `${#status}` (number of words)
- `$%status` or `${%status}` (number of characters)
- `@ status++` / `if ( status == 0 ) then` (maths expressions where the variable may (sometimes) be used without a `$` prefix).

Using a word boundary operator (`\b` in perl or augmented regexp, `\b`, `\>` or `[[:>:]]` in some implementations of BRE or ERE as non-standard extensions) would help with the first category of issues:

```
grep -P '\$status\b'
```

Without word boundary, that can be done by hand:

```
grep -E '\$status([^_[:alnum:]]|$)'
grep    '$status\([^_[:alnum:]].*\)\{0,1\}$'
```

Where we look for `$status` followed by either a character non-constituent of a variable name or the end of the line, or in BRE that don't have an alternation operator¹ but these days have `\{0,1\}` as an equivalent of ERE `?`, `$status` optionally followed by a non-variable-constituent and any number of characters up to the end of the line.

To address a few more:

```
grep -P '\$\{?[#%]?status\b'
grep -E '\$\{?[#%]?status([^_[:alnum:]]|$)'
grep    '${\{0,1\}[#%]\{0,1\}status\([^_[:alnum:]].*\)\{0,1\}$'
```

---

<sup>¹ Though some `grep` implementations have `\|` for that as a non-standard extension.</sup>

Comment: I think that I should  necessarily  use the double quotes with -E option because I also need its matching pattern for the OR operator, i.e. -E "A|B".

Comment: @lylklb, no single quotes are fine as well to escape `|`. See edit.

Comment: Thanks !  We have verified that the single quotes with -E option can also work fine as 'A|B'.   So it seems that there is almost no difference between the two type of quotes with -E option!